# SoC compute-resource usage monitor for single app

Tags: hardware, arm-processors, cpu, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I need to understand the **compute resource usage of a compute-intensive app**; this includes the **CPU** (ideally including the core ID), **GPU, DSP, AI Engine** in the processor (for Quallcom chips). I have found many ways to track the CPU usage per app, but am yet to find one that tracks the GPU or DSP usage per app.

What can I use to monitor the compute-resource usage of an app?

Comment: Can the device be rooted or not?

Comment: Preferably not, but I'm willing to explore that option.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm willing to root the phone, would it be possible to get that information?

Comment: The more custom (DSP/AI engine) stuff may require access to SOC SDKs, but if rooted, look into https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance